# Activate "Office Sharepoint Server Publishing" in 2007

Tags: feature-activation, publishing

When I try to activate the Office Sharepoint Server Publishing for the root level site, I keep getting

> One or more features must be turned
>   on before this feature can be
>   activated.

I tried to do

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -name PublishingPrerequisites -url http://website
```

-and that completed successfully then I did:

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -name PublishingResources -url http://website
```

-and that completed successfully, but even then when I try activate the Server Publishing through the layout config I get:

> One or more features must be turned on
>   before this feature can beb activated.

Answer (score 3):

The Site Collection feature Office Publishing Infrastructure must be enabled first.  It can only be enabled by someone with Site Collection Admin privledges.  Once that is enabled, the site feature can be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

From within the site collection that you want to enable it for, got to Site Actions >> Site Settings >> Site Collection Features. From within there, look for the "Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" entry and click the Activate button next to it. This should turn on all of the publishing features for the site collection.

Comment: I don't have a "Site Collection Features" under "Site Settings."  There's "Site Features", but when I try to activate it from there I get the same error: "One or more features must be turned on before this feature can beb activated."

Comment: You'll need Site Collection Administration rights to access Site Collection Features.